# Android ListView shows the list items in a dis-ordered manner

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, baseadapter

Sometimes list view repeating first 5 values sometimes 10 values, but the code don't shows any errors or warnings. and other issue is if i select one RadioButton it changes entire RadioButtons with same id(But different position)

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Anu Martin on 3/1/2016.
 */
public class QuestionAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    ArrayList<JSONObject> arrayList;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    Context context;
    public static final String KEY_QUESTION_TYPE="type"
            ,KEY_QUESTION="Q"
            ,KEY_QESTION_OPTION_YES="OPTYES"
            ,KEY_QUESTION_OPTION_NO="OPTNO"
            ,KEY_QUESTION_OPTION1="OPT1"
            ,KEY_QUESTION_OPTION2="OPT2"
            ,KEY_QUESTION_OPTION3="OPT3"
            ,KEY_QUESTION_OPTION4="OPT4"
            ,KEY_QUESTION_EXPLANATION="EXPL"
            ,KEY_ARRAY_QUESTION="A";
    public static final int QUESTION_TYPE_YESORNO=15
            ,QUESTION_TYPE_MULTIPLE_CHOICE=20
            ,QUESTION_TYPE_SHORT_ANSWER=25;

    public QuestionAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<JSONObject> arrayList){
        this.arrayList=arrayList;
        this.context=context;
        inflater=LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return arrayList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Log.e("getView",position+"");
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = this.arrayList.get(position);
            Log.d("getView",jsonObject.toString());
            int questionType=jsonObject.getInt(KEY_QUESTION_TYPE);
                switch (questionType){
                    case QUESTION_TYPE_YESORNO:{
                        ViewHolderYesOrNo mViewHolder;
                        if(convertView==null){
                            convertView=this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_question_yesorno,null);
                            mViewHolder=new ViewHolderYesOrNo(convertView);
                            convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
                        }else{
                            mViewHolder=(ViewHolderYesOrNo)convertView.getTag();
                        }
                        mViewHolder.question.setText(jsonObject.getString(KEY_QUESTION));
                        mViewHolder.type.setText(jsonObject.getInt(KEY_QUESTION_TYPE)+"");

                        if(jsonObject.getString(KEY_QUESTION_EXPLANATION)!=null) {
                            mViewHolder.explanation.setText(jsonObject.getString(KEY_QUESTION_EXPLANATION));
                            mViewHolder.explanation.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                    }break;
                    case QUESTION_TYPE_MULTIPLE_CHOICE:{
                        final ViewHolderMultipleChoice mViewHolder;
                        if(convertView==null){
                            convertView=this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_question_multiple_choice,null);
                            mViewHolder=new ViewHolderMultipleChoice(convertView);
                            convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
                        }else{
                            mViewHolder=(ViewHolderMultipleChoice)convertView.getTag();
                        }
                        mViewHolder.question.setText(jsonObject.getString(KEY_QUESTION));
                        mViewHolder.type.setText(jsonObject.getInt(KEY_QUESTION_TYPE)+"");
                        mViewHolder.explanation.setText("");

                        mViewHolder.option1.setText(jsonObject.getString(KEY_QUESTION_OPTION1));
                        mViewHolder.option2.setText(jsonObject.getString(KEY_QUESTION_OPTION2));
                        mViewHolder.option3.setText(jsonObject.getString(KEY_QUESTION_OPTION3));
                        mViewHolder.option4.setText(jsonObject.getString(KEY_QUESTION_OPTION4));

                        if(jsonObject.getString(KEY_QUESTION_EXPLANATION)!=null) {
                            mViewHolder.explanation.setText(jsonObject.getString(KEY_QUESTION_EXPLANATION));
                            mViewHolder.explanation.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }

                    }break;
                    case QUESTION_TYPE_SHORT_ANSWER:{
                        ViewHolderShortAnswer mViewHolder;
                        if(convertView==null){
                            convertView=this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_question_short_answer,null);
                            mViewHolder=new ViewHolderShortAnswer(convertView);
                            convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
                        }else{
                            mViewHolder=(ViewHolderShortAnswer)convertView.getTag();
                        }
                        mViewHolder.question.setText(jsonObject.getString(KEY_QUESTION));
                        mViewHolder.type.setText(jsonObject.getInt(KEY_QUESTION_TYPE)+"");
                        if(jsonObject.getString(KEY_QUESTION_EXPLANATION)!=null) {
                            mViewHolder.explanation.setText(jsonObject.getString(KEY_QUESTION_EXPLANATION));
                            mViewHolder.explanation.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                    }break;
                    default:{
                        if(convertView==null){
                            convertView=this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_question_not_available,null);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }catch (Exception e){

        }
        return convertView;
    }
    static class ViewHolderYesOrNo{
        public TextView question,type,explanation;
        public RadioGroup radioGroup;
        public RadioButton yes,no;

        public ViewHolderYesOrNo(View view){
            question=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rowQuestionYesNo);
            type=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.rowQuestionType);
            explanation=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.rowQuestionExplanation);
            radioGroup=(RadioGroup)view.findViewById(R.id.rowOptionRadioGroup);

            yes=(RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.rowOptionYes);
            no=(RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.rowOptionNo);
        }
    }

    static class ViewHolderMultipleChoice{
        public TextView question,type,explanation;
        public RadioGroup radioGroup;
        public RadioButton option1,option2,option3,option4;

        public ViewHolderMultipleChoice(View view){
            question=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rowQuestionYesNo);
            type=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.rowQuestionType);
            explanation=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.rowQuestionExplanation);
            radioGroup=(RadioGroup)view.findViewById(R.id.rowOptionRadioGroup);

            option1=(RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.rowOptionOne);
            option2=(RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.rowOptionTwo);
            option3=(RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.rowOptionThree);
            option4=(RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.rowOptionFour);
        }
    }

    static class ViewHolderShortAnswer{
        public TextView question,type,explanation;

        public ViewHolderShortAnswer(View view){
            question=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rowQuestionYesNo);
            type=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.rowQuestionType);
            explanation=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.rowQuestionExplanation);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's places like this that cause what you see.

> ```
> if(jsonObject.getString(KEY_QUESTION_EXPLANATION)!=null) {
>     mViewHolder.explanation.setText(jsonObject.getString(KEY_QUESTION_EXPLANATION));
>     mViewHolder.explanation.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
> }
> ```

In short, you forget else block.

**Whenever you get a view from your viewholder, it still has all values that were previously set.** When using only `if` part, and not using `else` part, you only change some values, while others remain unchanged.

In this case, when you jsonObject does not have KEY_QUESTION_EXPLANATION, it shows explanation from last item, therefore you need to add

```
else {
    mViewHolder.explanation.serVisibily(View.Invisible);//or Gone
}
```

EDIT:

Bolded part is what causes your issue. The flow is such:

1. Your adapter gets view. At first, it's null.
2. Your adapter checks for null view, and if it's null, it creates a new view and sets half of values(since other half is preset in xml).
3. When your view gets invisible(offscreen), and new view is needed, your adapter gets view, which IS NOT null.
4. Your adapter sets some values, not-set values remain from previous view.

You can easily fix this with my previously suggested `else` statement.

Comment: thanks for your help. but explanation view already set visibility as gone in row xml, and it work fine. the problem is while scroll the list view the list order change it self and duplicating list item.

when click on list item automatically triggers for all list items with same id

Comment: I might have not been clear enough. I'll update answer and clarify what's causing your problem.

Comment: i fixed it any way thanks @MariusKaunietis, the problem because of invisible view,